# How to synchronized iPhone contact to Outlook (I know how to do the other way around)?

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, itunes, iphone

I sync outlook to my iphone.

Contact on my outlook show up on iPhone.

Contact I added to my iPhone do not show up in Outlook.

I need them synchronized both way.

How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

connex.io allows you to sync your iPhone and Outlook contacts. Just set up an account and connect your devices and we take care of the rest.

Disclaimer: I am a Co-Founder of connex.io